# Method returning std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>

Tags: c++

As a continuation of a: [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968477/c-try-finally-how-to-free-memory#30968508), I came across a problem with
writing a method of a class which returns:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>
```

I get compiler errors when such a return type is written. There is some problem with delete operand or something ...

Generally, I've wanted to write a method which initializes vector and returns it.

Could anyone help me how to write it?

### EDIT:

I Get:
attempting to reference a deleted function  h:\pliki programów (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0

Here I have the following code snippet. Can I create such a method like this?

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> Class::TestMethod(int param)
{       
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> array;

    auto day = std::make_unique<Object>();          
    array.push_back(day);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: what compiler errors?

Comment: @MattMcNabb What is interesting, the error points me not to m ycode but to the xmemory0 file ...

Comment: there should be more error detail. anyway, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the error messages.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have posted a code to which compiler probably refers to.

Comment: Please post an MCVE. We don't know what `Object` and `Class` are. If it doesn't matter, they shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is actually coming from:

```
array.push_back(day);
```

This tries to put a copy of `day` in the vector, which is not permitted since it is unique.

Instead you could write `array.push_back( std::move(day) );` however the following would be better, replacing `auto day...`:

```
array.emplace_back();
```

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is deleted. That causes a problem in the line:

```
array.push_back(day);
```

Use

```
array.push_back(std::move(day));
```